# Unable to get wireless working, RT2800 PCI [1814:0601], rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error

Tags: wireless, networking, mythbuntu, mythtv

Partial noob here, wanted to try Mythbuntu to replace a dying Tivo, and am having problems with some of the basics. After a weekend of studying, I've learned a bit but I keep hitting dead ends I don't know quite how to overcome.

```
uname -a

Linux Shade 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Initial Behavior: Wireless networks would not show up in the "network manager"? (is that the name? I see an icon in the upper right of the GUI (Figured out running XFCE) that I click and it changes when I plug the ethernet cable).

```
lspci -nn

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT2800 802.11n PCI [1814:0601]
```

Using http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/FAQ mostly as a guide, I started by installing the latest and greatest compat-wireless for rt2x00 drivers.

Current Behavior: Fresh when restarting, I see SSIDs in the network manager and I try to connect to mine, a WPA2 protected network. I'm prompted for the password and enter it. The network manager icon swirls for about a minute and then it reprompts for my password. I know I have the right password, I deleted and retried my password information from a separate Windows machine and it worked as typed. Eventually I hit cancel and the SSIDs all disappear from the network manager.

```
iwlist wlan0 scan

wlan0     No scan results
```

Checking for, um, not sure, `dmesg` command was something I was typing a lot so I added it to my running paper notes. Looks like it's errors or notifications or some kind of log. The numbers on the left keep changing, maybe elapsed time or something.

```
dmesg | tail

[ 3321.935084] phy0 -> rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0.
[ 3381.899236] phy0 -> rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0.
[ 3441.855438] phy0 -> rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0.
[ 3501.819676] phy0 -> rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0.
[ 3561.779743] phy0 -> rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0.
[ 3621.738350] phy0 -> rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0.
[ 3681.697177] phy0 -> rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0.
[ 3741.655319] phy0 -> rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0.
[ 3801.613986] phy0 -> rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0.
[ 3861.572981] phy0 -> rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0.

Checked for "blocks", not really sure what this means, but I'm running on a newly built desktop

rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Also tried using iw, but it returned nothing.

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
```

And after running `dmesg` again I see the same types of error messages, with a different number in front of each line. I'm pretty sure I'm screwing up with wpa_supplicant:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -ctest.conf
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument

ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
Failed to initialize control interface '/var/run/wpa_supplicant'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
```

And my `test.conf` looks like, modified from the example from the wpa_supplicant site since I don't have a "wheel" group, figured I'd be fine with the sudo group

```
# allow frontend (e.g., wpa_cli) to be used by all users in 'wheel' group
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=sudo
#
# home network; allow all valid ciphers
network={
    ssid="Feroz"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
psk="******"
}
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, since the rt2x00 is supposedly supported so, dunno what's up. I'm not morally opposed to using ndis to use the Windows drivers, but the drivers are locked away behind InstallShield and I can't extract them from the installation file.

Any help would be appreciated so I don't spend another XX hours banging rocks together.

Comment: Are you using the 12.04 version of mythbuntu? I only ask because my rt2800usb had issues in previous versions of ubuntu but worked out of the box with normal 12.04. I cant say i have tried with mythbuntu though.Did you try your wireless before installing the latest drivers?

Comment: The download .iso indicated it was 12.04.1 64-bit, with the LiveCD wireless also wasn't working, which is when I started diving in to the issue that I decided to install anyway so I could actually reboot when instructions asked me to. :)

Comment: This is happening in 13.04 32 & 64 Bit. Tested myself. The easiest way I can think of getting the error is by either trying to reconnect to the same Router or while connected to it do a scan with iwlist. Both will make the driver go crazy. Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1060268